# Program to check if a window is opened or not during some time interval

Tags: c++, error-handling, timer, gui, winapi

I'm trying to write a program that will check if a window is opened or not, during a given time. I was able to do that, but now I'm trying to make my code look cleaner. I don't like how I implement the way I handle all possible error cases. Here is my current code:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    int nArgs = 0;
    LPWSTR* Name = CommandLineToArgvW((LPCWSTR)lpCmdLine, &nArgs);
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    if (Name[1] == NULL)
    {
       MessageBox(NULL, L"Please enter a time", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK); //No timer input  
    }
    else
    {
       std::wstring wsTimer = Name[1];
       std::string sTimer(wsTimer.begin(), wsTimer.end());
       string::size_type tTimer = sTimer.find_first_not_of("0123456789");
       if (tTimer != std::string::npos)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Invalid timer input", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK); //Letters present in timer input
        }
        else
        {
            int Timer = std::stoi(sTimer);
            if (Timer == 0)
            {
                 MessageBox(NULL, L"Invalid timer input", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK); //Input 0 as timer
            }
            else
            {
                 int i = 0;
                 while (i++ < Timer)
                 {
                    hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, *Name);
                    if (hwnd == NULL)
                    {
                         Sleep(1000);
                    }
                   else
                    {
                         return 0;
                    }
                 }
                 
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Window is not found", NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK); //Window not open, wrong name, not found
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Just way too many if/else blocks, are there suggestions on how I can improve it and make it cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably start by defining a function named `require` or something on that order:

```cpp
void message(wchar_t const *msg) {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, msg, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
}

template <typename F>
void require(F f, wchar_t const *errorString) {
    if (!f()) {
       message(errorString);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Note: I've also separated the call to MessageBox out into its own function, both for the sake of portability and because in real use `MessageBox` is likely to be annoying for a command-line application, so you'll probably soon want to switch to something like printing to `std::cerr`.

Given the widespread use and understanding of `argc` and `argv`, I'd (strongly) favor them over `nArgs` and `Names`.

Using those, your code for main could start off something like this:

```
int argc = 0;
wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &argc);

require([&]{ return argv[1] != nullptr; }, L"Please enter a time");
```

`std::stoi` can tell you how many characters it converted. I'd make use of that to simplify checking the input string a bit:

```
std::wstring wsDuration(argv[1]);
std::size_t count;

int duration = std::stoi(argv[1], &count);
require([&]{ return count == wsDuration.size(); }, L"Invalid Timer input");
require([&]{ return duration > 0; }, L"Invalid Timer Input");
```

As for the loop, your situation seems to fit well with a normal counted loop. I'd also generally prefer the standard library functions for sleeping.

```
for (int i=0; i<duration; i++) {
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, argv[0]);
    if (hwnd != nullptr)
        return 0;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
message(L"Window is not found");
```

Putting those together, we end up with something like this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::literals;

void message(wchar_t const *msg) {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, msg, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
}

template <typename F>
void require(F f, wchar_t const *errorString) {
    if (!f()) {
       message(errorString);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{

    int argc = 0;
    wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &argc);

    require([&]{ return argv[1] != nullptr; }, L"Please enter a time");

    std::wstring wsDuration(argv[1]);
    std::size_t count;

    int duration = std::stoi(argv[1], &count);
    require([&]{ return count == wsDuration.size(); }, L"Invalid Timer input");
    require([&]{ return duration > 0; }, L"Invalid Timer Input");

    for (int i=0; i<duration; i++) {
        HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, argv[0]);
        if (hwnd != nullptr)
            return 0;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
    message(L"Window is not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful and so much cleaner than what I had, although here if the user entered "a20" by accident for the timer, the message box does not show up. All the other error cases are good. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MinhHoang: Thinking about it, you're right: if `std::stoi` can't convert *any* of the input to a number, it throws an exception. I'll think a bit about a good way to fix that.

Comment: So I work around it a little bit and kinda combine our codes, here's what I got that validated the last error case:
`std::wstring wsDuration(argv[1]);`
`std::string sDuration(wsDuration.begin(), wsDuration.end());`
`string::size_type tDuration = sDuration.find_first_not_of("0123456789");`  
`require([&] { return tDuration == std::string::npos; }, L"Invalid Timer input (Letters in timer input)");`
`int duration = std::stoi(argv[1], &tDuration);`
`require([&] { return duration > 0; }, L"Invalid Timer Input (Must be more than 0");`
The code should work now